# A problem related to properties of Integer Ceiling Function?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $[x]$ denote the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. Suppose that $f(n)=2n-[\frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}{2}]$ and $g(n)=2n+[\frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}{2}]$ for each positive integer $n$.

Suppose that $A=\{f(1),f(2),f(3)...\}$ and $B=\{g(1),g(2),g(3)...\}$. Prove that every positive integer $m$ is an element of exactly one of $A$ or $B$.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: In short, we don't know what do you know and where to start. Show us what you know.

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma.** The sequence $b_n = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, \ldots]$ (the number $n$ occurs $n$ times) starting from $1$ has a explicit formula $b_n = \biggl\lfloor \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{8 n - 7}}{2} \biggr\rfloor$.

*Proof.* Omitted.

---

Then we have $f(n) = 2 n - b_n$ and $g(n) = 2 n + b_n$. Let’s look at some first terms of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$.

| $n$ | $1$ | $2$ | $3$ | $4$ | $5$ | $6$ | $7$ | $8$ | $9$ | $10$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $f(n)$ | $\color{red}{1}$ | $\color{blue}{2}$ | $\color{blue}{4}$ | $\color{red}{5}$ | $\color{red}{7}$ | $\color{red}{9}$ | $\color{blue}{10}$ | $\color{blue}{12}$ | $\color{blue}{14}$ | $\color{blue}{16}$ |
| $g(n)$ | $\color{red}{3}$ | $\color{blue}{6}$ | $\color{blue}{8}$ | $\color{red}{11}$ | $\color{red}{13}$ | $\color{red}{15}$ | $\color{blue}{18}$ | $\color{blue}{20}$ | $\color{blue}{22}$ | $\color{blue}{24}$ |
| $2 n$ | $2$ | $4$ | $6$ | $8$ | $10$ | $12$ | $14$ | $16$ | $18$ | $20$ |
| $b_n$ | $\color{red}{1}$ | $\color{blue}{2}$ | $\color{blue}{2}$ | $\color{red}{3}$ | $\color{red}{3}$ | $\color{red}{3}$ | $\color{blue}{4}$ | $\color{blue}{4}$ | $\color{blue}{4}$ | $\color{blue}{4}$ |

Notice the colors I attached to the cells. You may found some patterns in it, especially the parity of the numbers.

E.g., For even numbers, divide them into intervals with patterns $[r_{k - 1} + 2, r_k]$ where $r_k = 4 k (k + 1)$ being the right endpoints ($k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$).

I think the works left is just caseworking and showing some details.